# Cryptography package import fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

Attempting to run Python 3 code containing the `python-binance` and `OpenSSL` modueles failed on an import within the `cryptography` package. Here is a partial stack trace of the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to upgrade the cryptography package:

`pip3 install --upgrade cryptography`

I also verified the installation of required system packages:

`sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev`